# GrooveJoint2D - why does the Godot editor enforces a minimum value of 1 for initial_offset?

Tags: 2d, joints, godot-4

When you add a [`GrooveJoint2D`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_groovejoint2d.html) to the scene tree, the Godot editor limits the minimum value of the `initial_offset` property to `1 px`:

[image: Godot editor - GrooveJoint2D]

The [documentation](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_groovejoint2d.html#class-groovejoint2d-property-initial-offset) doesn't say anything about a minimum value of `1`.

Setting the property to zero through code *before* assigning `node_a` and `node_b` seems to work though and doesn't exhibit any adverse effect for my use case.

```
$MyGrooveJoint.initial_offset = 0
$MyGrooveJoint.node_a = $MyNodeA.get_path()
$MyGrooveJoint.node_b = $MyNodeB.get_path()
```

Still there might be cases where an `initial_offset` of `0` could cause problems, which I'd like to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `initial_offset` of `0.0` is OK.

*The rest of this answer is how I confirmed that.*

---

A good excuse to check the source code.

We find `initial_offset` declared like this ([source](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/blob/a7276f1ce0c2911216a2c4718efddab98ddffd8f/scene/2d/joint_2d.h#L105)):

```
real_t initial_offset = 25.0;
```

And looking for usage (in [joint_2d.cpp](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/blob/a7276f1ce0c2911216a2c4718efddab98ddffd8f/scene/2d/joint_2d.cpp)) does not reveal any issue with it bean zero. However, it is used to compute a variable `anchor_B` which is passed to `joint_make_groove` in `joint_make_groove` ([source](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/blob/a7276f1ce0c2911216a2c4718efddab98ddffd8f/scene/2d/joint_2d.cpp#L325)):

```
void GrooveJoint2D::_configure_joint(RID p_joint, PhysicsBody2D *body_a, PhysicsBody2D *body_b) {
    Transform2D gt = get_global_transform();
    Vector2 groove_A1 = gt.get_origin();
    Vector2 groove_A2 = gt.xform(Vector2(0, length));
    Vector2 anchor_B = gt.xform(Vector2(0, initial_offset));

    PhysicsServer2D::get_singleton()->joint_make_groove(p_joint, groove_A1, groove_A2, anchor_B, body_a->get_rid(), body_b->get_rid());
}
```

As you can see, a value of zero in `initial_offset` results in `anchor_B` being set at the origin of the `GrooveJoint2D`.

We find `joint_make_groove` in godot_physics_server_2d.cpp ([source](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/blob/a7276f1ce0c2911216a2c4718efddab98ddffd8f/servers/physics_2d/godot_physics_server_2d.cpp#L1127)):

```
void GodotPhysicsServer2D::joint_make_groove(RID p_joint, const Vector2 &p_a_groove1, const Vector2 &p_a_groove2, const Vector2 &p_b_anchor, RID p_body_a, RID p_body_b) {
    GodotBody2D *A = body_owner.get_or_null(p_body_a);
    ERR_FAIL_COND(!A);

    GodotBody2D *B = body_owner.get_or_null(p_body_b);
    ERR_FAIL_COND(!B);

    GodotJoint2D *prev_joint = joint_owner.get_or_null(p_joint);
    ERR_FAIL_COND(prev_joint == nullptr);

    GodotJoint2D *joint = memnew(GodotGrooveJoint2D(p_a_groove1, p_a_groove2, p_b_anchor, A, B));

    joint_owner.replace(p_joint, joint);
    joint->copy_settings_from(prev_joint);
    memdelete(prev_joint);
}
```

Which ends up passing the `p_b_anchor` to `GodotGrooveJoint2D`... Which we find in godot_joints_2d.h and godot_joints_2d.cpp. First of all, it will convert it to the local space of the second body in the constructor ([source](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/blob/a7276f1ce0c2911216a2c4718efddab98ddffd8f/servers/physics_2d/godot_joints_2d.cpp#L368)):

```
B_anchor = B->get_inv_transform().xform(p_b_anchor);
```

And then, in `setup` the computation of `rB` would be the zero vector ([source](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/blob/a7276f1ce0c2911216a2c4718efddab98ddffd8f/servers/physics_2d/godot_joints_2d.cpp#L300)):

```
    rB = B->get_transform().basis_xform(B_anchor);

    // calculate tangential distance along the axis of rB
    real_t td = (B->get_transform().get_origin() + rB).cross(n);
    // calculate clamping factor and rB
    if (td <= ta.cross(n)) {
        clamp = 1.0f;
        rA = ta - A->get_transform().get_origin();
    } else if (td >= tb.cross(n)) {
        clamp = -1.0f;
        rA = tb - A->get_transform().get_origin();
    } else {
        clamp = 0.0f;
        //joint->r1 = cpvsub(cpvadd(cpvmult(cpvperp(n), -td), cpvmult(n, d)), a->p);
        rA = ((-n.orthogonal() * -td) + n * d) - A->get_transform().get_origin();
    }
```

Although, I believe that is no problem. Then we pass `rB` to `k_tensor`:

```
    // Calculate mass tensor
    k_tensor(A, B, rA, rB, &k1, &k2);
```

Which looks like this ([source](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/blob/a7276f1ce0c2911216a2c4718efddab98ddffd8f/servers/physics_2d/godot_joints_2d.cpp#L231)):

```
static inline void
k_tensor(GodotBody2D *a, GodotBody2D *b, Vector2 r1, Vector2 r2, Vector2 *k1, Vector2 *k2) {
    // calculate mass matrix
    // If I wasn't lazy and wrote a proper matrix class, this wouldn't be so gross...
    real_t k11, k12, k21, k22;
    real_t m_sum = a->get_inv_mass() + b->get_inv_mass();

    // start with I*m_sum
    k11 = m_sum;
    k12 = 0.0f;
    k21 = 0.0f;
    k22 = m_sum;

    r1 -= a->get_center_of_mass();
    r2 -= b->get_center_of_mass();

    // add the influence from r1
    real_t a_i_inv = a->get_inv_inertia();
    real_t r1xsq = r1.x * r1.x * a_i_inv;
    real_t r1ysq = r1.y * r1.y * a_i_inv;
    real_t r1nxy = -r1.x * r1.y * a_i_inv;
    k11 += r1ysq;
    k12 += r1nxy;
    k21 += r1nxy;
    k22 += r1xsq;

    // add the influnce from r2
    real_t b_i_inv = b->get_inv_inertia();
    real_t r2xsq = r2.x * r2.x * b_i_inv;
    real_t r2ysq = r2.y * r2.y * b_i_inv;
    real_t r2nxy = -r2.x * r2.y * b_i_inv;
    k11 += r2ysq;
    k12 += r2nxy;
    k21 += r2nxy;
    k22 += r2xsq;

    // invert
    real_t determinant = k11 * k22 - k12 * k21;
    ERR_FAIL_COND(determinant == 0.0);

    real_t det_inv = 1.0f / determinant;
    *k1 = Vector2(k22 * det_inv, -k12 * det_inv);
    *k2 = Vector2(-k21 * det_inv, k11 * det_inv);
}
```

We see that it gets the `rB` argument in the `r2` parameter. We also see that `r2` is offset by the center of mass of the second body. And finally that if this somehow resulted in an invalid matrix, we would have an error.

Thus, as long as you are not getting an error in the output of your code, it is fine.

Comment: Thanks for the deep dive into the code! So we should propably create an issue in the github project so the minium value that can be entered in the UI will be changed to 0.0? This would also further confirm whether 0.0 is a valid value.

Comment: @zett42 sure. I could not find an issue about it.

Comment: I'm a little bit hesitant as I'm still very new to Godot. If it's not asked too much, would you like to create the issue? With the research you have already done, you can propably formulate it much better than me.